# How get data from response with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get some data and display data on the page.  As you can see from the screenshot the user data is coming back from GET call.  Two questions are first obviously the error on the "setData(result.data);" line.  Second, once that error is corrected, how do I correctly map the data in my return statement?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function UserList() {

    const [data, setData] = useState({ data: [] });

    useEffect(() => {

        const url = 'https://zzs34n9ig88f.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/';

        const fetchData = async () => {

            const result = await axios.post(url, {
                "httpMethod": "GET",
                "queryStringParameters": {
                  "TableName": "Users"
                }
              })
              .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
              }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
              });
            setData(result.data);
        };
        fetchData();
        }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Users</p>
        {data.data.map(item => (
            <div>
                <span>{item.email}</span>
            </div>
        ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default UserList
```

**debug info:**

[image]

**Postman:**

[image]

Comment: Try `.then(response=>{ console.log(response); return resposne; })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't return the resolved value in your `.then()` clause.
You should skip using `.then()`:

```
const result = await axios.post(url, {
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "queryStringParameters": {
        "TableName": "Users"
    }
});
try {
    console.log(result)
    setData(result.data);
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e)
}
```

Alternatively, you could return `response`, but it's not really advisable to mix up `async/await` and `.then()`.

```
const result = await axios.post(url, {
        "httpMethod": "GET",
        "queryStringParameters": {
            "TableName": "Users"
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
setData(result.data);
```

Comment: What about the mapping?  I've added another image to original post to show the format it's coming back with.

Answer (score 2):

As I can conclude from the caption of your response, before setting your state, just do the following:

```js
let list = JSON.parse(result.data.body);

setData(list.Items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const fetchData = async () => {

            const result = await axios.post(url, {
                "httpMethod": "GET",
                "queryStringParameters": {
                  "TableName": "Users"
                }
              })
              .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                return response; // return response here
              }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
              });
            setData({data:JSON.parse(result.data.body).Items}); // setData like this
        };
        fetchData();
        }, []);
```